# NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/settings/AbsSettings when "show compile:full-classpath" in Play project?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

When I execute `show compile:full-classpath` in the Play console I get:

```
[error] (drivetag-play/compile:compile) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/settings/AbsSettings
```

I'm attempting to add `scala-reflect-2.10.0` to the classpath because when I try to compile the whole project it gives me the same error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you remove the `scala-reflect` dependency and verify `show compile:full-classpath` works? In fact, it corresponds to `show fullClasspath` since `compile` is the default configuration and `-` (the dash) is discouraged. How did you add the dep to `build.sbt`? Add the snippets to your question so it's easier to read.

Comment: without that is the same. the problem was since the beginning, i added scala-reflect to the classpath because it thought it was missing